# How to make a data queue in AS400 that is triggered by a SQL trigger?

Tags: sql, triggers, queue, ibm-midrange

I would need to make a data queue that is triggered by mine SQL Trigger;
The SQL Trigger is already done but I don't know how to implement the data queue

Comment: You seem to have a lot of RPG/IBM i questions. You should check out the [midrange.com](http://midrange.com) mailing lists. The [RPG-L](http://murl.me/rpgl) and [MIDRANGE-L](http://murl.me/midrangel). There are a lot more experts on there that may be able to better answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks. I've post a question but I find very hard to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, SQL is intended to act upon databases.  Interacting with operating system objects is not easily done.  However, DB2 for i will allow you to execute programs, including the API to send a message to a data queue: QSNDDTAQ.  It is ugly.

```
call qsnddtaq ('DTAQ      ', 'LIBRARY   ', x'0008F', 'From SQL')
```

The parameters are:

1. Data queue name (10 bytes)
2. Data queue library name (10 bytes)
3. Message length (packed(5,0))
4. Message contents

If the SQL trigger uses variables rather than literals it will not need to do anything special to format the length - the literal shown is what a packed(5,0) looks like internally.

If I were assigned this task I would create a CL program and call that rather than the API.  Then I would be able to use packed(15,5) for the length parameter, which is the 'natural' cross-language number length as well as provide for trapping errors.

Comment: +1 - Agreed; if you're going to talk to a non-SQL object, wrap it in a CL or RPGLE program, and have the trigger call that instead.  (Alternatively, just make a table that you'll dump stuff into as a queue, and have a recurring monitor job...)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know much about it, for me a CL program would fit too (I think) as long as I can do it (because I don't even know where to put the files in order to be executed by the as400). But in this case if I would like to just send the data changed (I know what changed because thr trigger) how exactly I do? The table is: LIBRARY.TABLE, fields: [a1, a2, a3], the sql query: "SELECT a1, a2, a3 from LIBRARY.TABLE WHERE ??what changed??"

Comment: I don't understand the business problem.  I think you are saying that if A1 changes, you want to send the contents of A1 to the data queue.  If A2 changes you want to send the contents of A2 to the data queue.  I guess that you want separate messages for each field that changed?  Normally, data queues are used to communicate between processes.  What does the other process want to see in the data queue message?

Comment: It might be best simply to register a new external stored proc against the QSYS/QSNDDTAQ API. Parameter definitions can then be assigned however needed for the specific usage.